# Template of this article

Tags: templates

Doing some research in physics I have come across nicelly formated LaTeX document which can be found here:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5621v1.pdf

What could be minimal LaTeX document to reproduce such formatting? The properties which I do like are:

- Choice of font
- Picked margin sizes
- Line spacing
- Title nummeration with Greek numbers
- Indentation of parragraphs

Comment: The Title Font is the usual `cmss` obtained with `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}`, in boldface. The default one for the text is the `cmr`, you don't need to change anything to use it with LaTeX. Also for the Greek letters.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the current state of your template and explain the problems you are having implementing the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the source as for most documents on arxiv:

http://arxiv.org/format/1303.5621v1

Comment: It seems that uploaded sorce archive is broken. Does it open well on your computer?

Comment: It's not broken for me, but it is mis-named. Rename the downloaded file to something with a `.tar.gz` extension, and it will open with `gunzip` and `tar` on a Unix system, or with 7-Zip on a Windows system.